# How to show screen with two option again and again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to screen with two same option when user click same row  in jQuery mobile.
I am making a demo in which i have one button(add game) on click button it become disable and make two option (add game, game name) in list.If user click add game (1 option it show again two option in next screen add game, game name )it will go to next screen with two option if user choose first option.if user choose second option at any time it show drop box(drop down).on selecting any value from drop down it create a row of that. ?

Diagram ..

```
          ADD GAME(button)
           |
       (disable button)
        ADD GAME
        GAME NAME
          |
  Go to new screen with two option
        ADD GAME
        GAME NAME
          |
it will display this if user select first option..
```

If user select second option then it show drop down and add value of game name in .list 
http://jsfiddle.net/gQnBW/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#addGame').click(function(){

         $(this).addClass('ui-disabled');
$("#listview").append("<li>Add Game</li>"); 
        $("#listview").append("<li>Game Name</li>"); 
         $("#listview").listview("refresh");

    }) 

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated this, now everything is functional but the dropdown selector is not being styled properly.

HTML

```
<div data-role="page">


<a  data-role="button" class="addGame">Add Game</a>

            <ul id='listview' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'></ul>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.ui-hidden{
    display:none !important;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var gameSelector = '<li id="chooseGame"><span></span><select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1" > <option value="Default">Select a Game</option><option value="GAME 1">GAME 1</option> <option value="GAME 2">GAME 2</option> <option value="GAME 3">GAME 3</option> <option value="GAME 4">GAME 4</option>  </select></li>'

    $(document).on('click', '.addGame', function(){

        $(this).addClass('ui-hidden');
        $("#listview").append(gameSelector); 
        $("#listview").append("<li class='addGame'>Add Game</li>"); 
        $("#listview").listview("refresh");

    }); 

    $(document).on('click', '.changeGame', function(){

        $(this).parent().append(gameSelector); 
        $(this).remove();
       $("#listview").listview("refresh");

    });     

    $(document).on('change', '#select-choice-1', function(){

         var gamename = $('#select-choice-1').val();
         $(this).parent().append("<li class='changeGame'>"+gamename+"</li>");
        $(this).remove();
       $("#listview").listview("refresh");

    }); 



});
```

New fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4gHJ2/